# Why would this say TypeError: users.map is not a function when my logs say the data in question is an array?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to perform a POST request using fetch, and my code does make the POST request successfully. However, once react tries to rerender after the post request (where I call setUsers to in order to update the state), it errors out telling me the `users. map` is not a function. I just don't understand why it would be like that b/c I even took measures to copy the state first in a new variable, push the new item onto that variable, and then I finally pass the variable to users in the setter. Here is my code.

```js
const App = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState(
    {
      id: Math.round(Math.random() * 1000000),
      name: "",
      age: "",
    },
    [users]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:4000/")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => setUsers(res))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch("http://localhost:4000/", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(formData),
    })
      .then((res) => {
        res.json().then((data) => {
          const newUsersList = users;
          newUsersList.push(data);
          console.log(newUsersList);
          setUsers(() => {
            return {
              newUsersList,
            };
          });
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };

  const handleInput = (e) => {
    setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="name">Username </label>
          <input onChange={handleInput} id="name" type="text" name="name" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="age">Age </label>
          <input onChange={handleInput} id="age" type="text" name="age" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Create User</button>
        </div>
      </form>
      <ul>
        {users.map((user) => {
          return <li key={user.id}>{user.name}</li>;
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `setUser` implementation inside `handleSubmit` like so :-

```
const newUsersList = [...users];
newUsersList.push(data);
setUsers(newUsersList);
```

What you earlier did was wrapping your state i.e `newUsersList` inside the `{ }` which make it an object like `{newUsersList:content of newUsersList}` and setting it as state via returning the same from the **state updator's callback** and now when accessing `.map` on this new state it will fail since it's no longer an array.

So just simply make a copy of your existing state i.e. `users` by using the **spread** operator and do your push operation on new list and set it as state.

You can also do the following :-

```
setUsers((prevUsers)=>[...prevUsers,data]);
```

Here you're getting the previous state via a **callback** function and simply returning a new array with the contents of `prevUsers` + `data`.

This is also doable (same as first one in essence) :-

```
setUsers([...users,data]);
```

but when acting on previous state, it's good to make use of that callback function since `prevUsers` would never be a **stale** state in case **closures** start causing that.

Comment: I did have a couple of problems though. The first way that you showed stopped the error, but the page didn't refresh, and the second way with the callback caused a rerender as expected, but it posted  the data twice. I did end up trying ```setUser(prevUsers => [...prevUsers]), and then it only updated once which is the intended behave iour.

Comment: Another thing that worked was just doing setUser([...users]);

Comment: I think in first one instead of assigning `newUsersList` to `[...users]`, you assigned it to `users` like how @keimeno did but that's not right since we need a copy. To make a copy we use `...`. Now everytime you make a copy even without adding `data`, a render will occur. So I am not sure why simply making a copy of your existing state without the new `data` is getting the new `data` as well in your rendered output. You have to either add `data` (to your copied state) using `push` or simply do the ```[...state,data]``` bit.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `handleSubmit` function you have the following statement:

```
setUsers(() => {
  return {
    newUsersList,
  };
});
```

It must be the following instead:

```
setUsers(newUsersList);
```

since the argument passed to `setUsers` shouldn't be a function, it should be an array.